# How does the OS feed machine code to CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu

When we run an executable,the machine code is called one by one in the CPU,but how does the OS feed each instruction to CPU?

What's the internals?

Comment: Might as well hit up Wikipedia for this one buddy. . .

Answer (score 4):

The [**loader**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29) loads binaries from disk into memory, [**relocating**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29) jump and load operations as required. From there, the CPU just loads the code from memory and executes it.

Comment: +1 for being slightly better than M. Hewgill´s answer.

Answer (score 2):

The OS sets the Instruction Pointer (IP) register of the CPU to the beginning of the code to execute (which is in RAM). The CPU starts executing instructions in sequence.

Comment: how's that actually carried out?

Comment: At the simplest level, the IP register is set with something like a JMP instruction. I suggest you find and study some introductory materials on CPU architecture.

Comment: It's a close-run thing.  But M. Vazquez-Abram's answer is slightly better in that it makes it clear that the CPU "feeds" itself.  This answer still leaves open the implication that the operating system is some sort of intermediary that "feeds" machine code to a processor, which of course it isn't (since the operating system is _itself_ machine code).

Answer (score 1):

The OS does not feed instructions to the CPU, the CPU pulls instructions from memory on its own based in the PC (Program Counter) or IP (Instruction Pointer) or whatever other term you want to use.  The OS itself is just a bunch of instructions being fed into the processor.  The processor does not know the OS from any other program.  The OS reads the machine code portion of an executable (executables used by well known OSes like windows and linux have more information in the file other than just the binary or executable portion) and puts it in ram somewhere.  And essentially the OS branches to the entry point instruction in the executable, by changing the PC.  Many different ways to do this, branching, changing the return value on an interrupt, processor specific methods, etc.

Petzold has a book called "Code", pretty good, give it a read.

Comment: Just to add: Intel calls the register pointing to the instruction it is executing the "IP" or Instruction Pointer.  It's EIP in 32-bit processors running in 32-bit mode, and RIP in 64-bit processors running in 64-bit mode (the E stands for Extended, still don't know what the R stands for)

Answer (score 0):

The OS sets the Instruction Pointer of the processor to the memory address of where the instruction for the program is and the processor does the work from there. I could get more technical but I don't know how much information you want.